# Connecting to Multiple TCP Servers From Client C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client

Making the properties TcpClient and IPEndPoint appear to have fixed my issue! If anyone could explain why this is the case I would appreciate it. I do usually declare my class objects static but I don't entirely understand why it works this way.

I'd like to start by saying the usual, I've googled and googled but haven't found anything answering my question so please point me if there is already an answer to this question.

I have written successfully a TCP server and client in C#, however I would like my client to be able to connect to multiple servers. To be clear this is **not** a server with multiple clients connected to it, I had no issues configuring that.
Here is a little picture explaining what I mean:

[image: Client Connects to 2 Servers]

Pretty, I know. But in all seriousness I can't get this to work. I met with the error: *A connect request was made on an already connected socket*
I have a class called client, with a TcpClient and an IPEndPoint:

```
public  Client(IPEndPoint ip) 
    {
        client = new TcpClient(); 
        this.ip = ip; 
    }
```

This class has methods connect, send, receive etc. The issue comes when I do something like this:

```
Client host = new Client(hosts.ElementAt(0));
IPEndPoint ipe = hosts.ElementAt(0);
```

EDIT: This contructor occurs in a different method than the method the "host" constructor does
    Client client = new Client(ipe);
    client.ConnectAsync();
    host.ConnectAsync();
Now originally I tried to use the new async methods and the await feature, it worked fine when it was only one host but on the second it began to error. I thought perhaps it was becuase I was using the same method and it was attempting to connect before the first await had completed, it would try to connect again on the first IP, no idea if that makes any sense but basically I thought, well I will just create a new thread for each connect attempt like so:

```
    public void ConnectAsync()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { ConnectAsyncMethod(); });
    }

        private void ConnectAsyncMethod()
    {
        Thread connectThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect(ip.Address, ip.Port);
                this.clientStream = client.GetStream();
                ReceiveAsync();
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException ns)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        });
        connectThread.Start();
    }
```

Even though the connect is run on a new thread, I still get the same error, but why?
Could anyone point me towards a solution and hopefully explain where the flaws in my thinking lie? I am now thinking perhaps it is something in the way sockets are handled but I'm really not sure.
I appreciate any help, thank you everyone.

Comment: Is `client` (the instance variable in the Client class) a static member? What is your endpoint?

Comment: @JasonFry

private TcpClient client;

private IPEndPoint ip;

It is not static, and the endpoint changes depending on the server but it is either resolved from DNS or explicitly typed. The first connection actually goes through, then the second attempt fails. I added a picture of my little debug form so you can maybe get an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need **multiple** `Client` objects to establish **multiple connections** to different addresses (or the same in fact). For example, you could have a `Client ClientA` connect to Server A and have a `Client ClientB` connect to Server B. You cannot have the same `Client` object connect two times to diffrent or the same address.

Comment: Look back at the question, I established two different Client objects:
    Client host = new Client(hosts.ElementAt(0));
    Client client = new Client(ipe);

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Sorry, I looked too fast. This is strange, because this error should occure if you try to connect the same TCPClient twice. Another problem I could see is maybe you would be trying to connect to the same address and the same port twice. Have you checked that ?

Comment: Well here is where it gets really weird,
First Client connects on IP: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:2000

Second calls connect, I get the error above, saying that I was connecting on XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:2000 even though the second was constructed was connected to YY.YYY.YYY.YY:3023
So yes it would appear it is using the same IP to connect, despite the use of two different client objects

Comment: `Client host = new Client(hosts.ElementAt(0));`
`IPEndPoint ipe = hosts.ElementAt(0);`
`Client client = new Client(ipe);` Aren't you sendind `hosts.ElementAt(0)` to both constructor (after all, `ipe` is equal to `hosts.ElementAt(0)`

Comment: My apologies, those are actually in two different submethods. configHost() does the host and configClient() does client. Making the properties static fixed the issue I was having. Just not entirely sure why...

Comment: So your problem is fixed ? If it's the case I was happy to help you !

Comment: It would appear so, I'll have to do a little more testing but so far so good!

Answer (score -1):

This is strange.Maybe you would check whether the 2nd client port conflicts with the first client which will result in the error.
Here I found the official manual of this(10056):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/aa924071(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have checked the error code, it would appear it is connecting on the same address despite two different constructors, I just can't figure out why or how to fix it for that matter